# Umbraco, list media files, sort by size

Tags: umbraco, image-size, umbraco6

I am working with Umbraco 6 and searching for a way to know what are the "heaviest" medias (pictures) of my site.

I have a media folder per site.

And I would like to be able to list all the medias from that folder, sorted descending by size.

Say

**MySiteMediaFolder**

```
video          === 115.5 Mb
restr          ===   4.3 Mb
my.pdf         ===   1.3 Mb
...
small.gif      ===   0.01 Mb
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use Umbraco Examine?

Comment: Hello @JaredChu, there are indexers and searchers... what is to try?

Comment: you need to implement both to make it work

Comment: what do you mean by "implement"? I need a list of pictures sorted by the size, what do you mean when you say I need to "implement" the indexers or searchers?

Comment: sorry maybe I'm wrong, cuz I thought you want to search your media files

Comment: updated the OP to be more clear on the matter